# Error for pyspark converting dataframe to rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd, pyspark

My codes are:

```
 sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
 table = sqlContext.sql("select * from table").rdd

 print table.count()
```

when I submit my codes to cluster, I got error below:

> File xxxx/dataframe.py  line80 in applySchema
>   TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

I just want to convert a dataframe to rdd.

Comment: I solved it myself. Python Version of each slave must be the same. I got this error because one of my slaves has a different python version. I changed the version and the problem was solved